# Use value from qry using Count and update to a table in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a query which counts the number of records for each subset:

```
SELECT tbl_Interpolation.Unit, tbl_Interpolation.Car, tbl_Interpolation.Pad, 
Nz(Count(tbl_Interpolation.CalenderDate),0) AS NumRecords
FROM tbl_Interpolation
GROUP BY tbl_Interpolation.Unit, tbl_Interpolation.Car, tbl_Interpolation.Pad;
```

I also have a field in tbl_CalcReg called NumRecords which have the same unit, car and pad as the query above, so where these variables are the same e.g tbl_CalcReg.Pad=qry_NumRecords.pad i would like to update the field NumRecords.

Again i am having an issue with the aggregate function, i have looked at DCount() but i cannot seem to find a way to implement it without using criteria, as i just want to count how many calenderdates there are for each Unit/Car/Pad combination. I got as far as DCOUNT("CalenderDate", "tbl_Interpolation", "*") but i really havent a clue as to how i can make this into an update query?

Please help.

Best Regards
Donna

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use `DCount()` with a query like this

```sql
UPDATE tbl_CalcReg SET NumRecords = 
DCount("CalenderDate", "tbl_Interpolation", "Unit=" & Unit & " AND Car=" & Car & " AND Pad=" & Pad)
```

assuming that [Unit], [Car], and [Pad] are numeric fields. If they are text fields then you'll need to put quotes (`'`) around the values and escape any quotes in the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a correlated subquery.  The following does the update for all records:

```
update tbl_CalcReg
    set NumRecords = (select count(*)
                      from tbl_Interpolation as i
                      where i.unit = tbl_CalcReg.unit and i.car = tbl_CalcReg.car and
                            i.pad = tbl_CalcReg.pad
                     )
```

You can add this `where` clause if you only want changed records:

```
where NumRecords <> (select count(*)
                     from tbl_Interpolation as i
                     where i.unit = tbl_CalcReg.unit and i.car = tbl_CalcReg.car and
                           i.pad = tbl_CalcReg.pad
                    )
```

EDIT:

MS Access supports `UPDATE`/`JOIN`.  In that case:

```
update tbl_CalcReg JOIN
       (select unit, car, pad, count(*) as cnt
        from tbl_Interpolation
        group by unit, car, pad
       ) as i
       on i.unit = tbl_CalcReg.unit and i.car = tbl_CalcReg.car and i.pad = tbl_CalcReg.pad
    set NumRecords = i.cnt
```

Comment: @Beth . . . It should be Access syntax (although Access has rather arcane differences from most other SQL dialects, so there might be some small error).

Comment: Hi Gordon, I just tried your first suggestion and im still receiving the Must use an updateable query error, should this use the DCount() instead?

Comment: I usually end up with 'not an updateable query' errors, end up storing the results I need to a table to get the update to work.

Comment: Hi Beth, thats what im trying to avoid, i have so many stored tables due to not being able to update values its all getting a bit crazy, i'm starting to think my database has outgrown access.